# Stop HTML5 audio from looping when iOS Safari is closed

Tags: javascript, ios, html, ios6, html5-audio

Okay, so I've got something as simple as this:

```
<audio autoplay='autoplay' loop='loop' id='audio' controls>
  <source src='http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.ogg'/>
  <source src='http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3'/>
</audio>
```

Now, when I play the audio on an iOS device, it loops fine and everything, *however*, when I close the browser window, or switch tabs, it just keeps on looping and the only way to pause it is if I shut the browser tab. I tried removing the `loop='loop'` and replaying it `onended` with JavaScript, <strike>*and that works, but with audio that is about 1.5 mins long, it can still be pretty annoying.*</strike> but that didn't work either because the `ended` event fires even when the browser isn't open.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x843X/) in which the sound is the first one I could find online, but note that my actual sound is pretty long, so I do need to `pause` it when the browser window is closed.

I've tried pausing it `onblur`, `onunload` and `onbeforeunload` to no avail. Is there a way to stop the audio from playing in the background?

Comment: had asked the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019990/html5-audio-music-does-not-stop-even-after-navigating-away-from-the-website but no result as yet

Comment: @Ani Managed to figure it out! Posted an answer on your question as well :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed to find a solution:

Make use of a loop, to check if the user is on the webpage. Store the time.

```
var lastSeen;
var loop = function (){
    lastSeen = Date.now();
    setTimeout(loop, 50);
};
loop();

var music = document.getElementById('music');
music.addEventListener('timeupdate', function (){
    if(Date.now() - lastSeen > 100){
        this.pause();
    }
}, false);
```

That's roughly what my file looks like. Since the `timeupdate` event fires on an audio element continually if it's playing, I only have to check when my loop was last called. If it was called more than 100ms ago, I pause the music. Worked like a charm on the iPad I tested on.

Comment: I combined this with requestAnimationFrame rather than a "timeupdate" listener so that I could reload images that might have been kicked from the cache upon the tab losing focus.  While this method worked, it will also register on page scrolling and anywhere code execution time exceeds your loop interval, which is undesired behavior.

Comment: Images get kicked from the cache and don't reload themselves? Never heard of that. The page scrolling problem you can probably get around with a simple flag that you toggle when scrolling starts. The execution time problem I'm aware of, but I can't really think of a *solution* to that. Best I think you could do is increase the `100` to a bigger value