# iPhone Safari - Pause html audio when pressing home button

Tags: iphone, html, audio, background

I have an audio element inside my page that starts playing at a button click.

Is there a way to **pause** the audio when the user presses the iPhone **HOME** button and Safari goes into **background**?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of a loop, to check if the user is on the webpage. Store the time.

```
var lastSeen;
var loop = function (){
    lastSeen = Date.now();
    setTimeout(loop, 50);
};
loop();

var music = document.getElementById('music');
music.addEventListener('timeupdate', function (){
    if(Date.now() - lastSeen > 100){
        this.pause();
    }
}, false);
```

**source: [Stop HTML5 audio from looping when iOS Safari is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414654/stop-html5-audio-from-looping-when-ios-safari-is-closed/14438227#14438227)**