# iOS6/7 stop sound going to background using web audio API

Tags: javascript, html, ios6, ios7, web-audio-api

There are different solutions for the issue when you go to the background in the iPhone or iPad and the sound continuous playing, the most of them for the [HMTL5 audio tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414654/stop-html5-audio-from-looping-when-ios-safari-is-closed), but are not relevant if you are using Web Audio API because there are not an event like ***"timeupdate"*** and is a different concept of course. The **[Page Visibility API](https://gist.github.com/addyosmani/1122546)** works in iOS7 only if you change of tab, but doesn't if you go to the background, in iOS6 not at all.

Someone knows any way to stop/mute a sound using **Web Audio API** if you go to the background in iOS6 or iOS7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect when safari is going background, you can use window's events called `pageshow` and `pagehide` (but this you already found out).

```
document.addEventListener('pageshow',function(){
    // Do something here
}, false);

document.addEventListener('pagehide',function(){
    // Do something here
}, false);
```

You can also use the [PageVisibility API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/pagevisibility/intro/) ([available since iOS7](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pagevisibility)) to check if the tab has changed.

```js
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function(){
    if (document.hidden) {
        // Tab out of focus
    }
    else {
        // Tab on focus
    }
},false);
```

Note that this code should work on safari since iOS7, but some browsers needs prefixes.

Comment: Finally I used the "pageshow" && "pagehide" in combination with https://gist.github.com/addyosmani/1122546 and works quite good. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Auto-solved 80%. These are the unique events triggered when you go to the background and after that return to Safari, tested on both iOS.

```
 window.addEventListener("pageshow", function(evt){ 
    //fooBarCode
 }, false);
 window.addEventListener("pagehide", function(evt){ 
   //fooBarCode 
}, false);
```

This works only when you go to the background, but when you change of tab isn't a valid solution, any ideas?