# How does youtube web prevent playing from control center on safari iOS

Tags: javascript, ios

I was trying to stop a video on Safari for iOS, when the browser goes in background. I was able to do that through [Page Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API).

On iOS's home screen, if I open the Control Center and press play button, it normally plays the last Safari's content.

What I'm trying to achieve is a Youtube Web mobile-like behavior: it is able to prevent this behavior. If you close Safari with a tab running Youtube, you are not able to press play in the control center and play the content.

I've already tried `e.preventDefault()` behavior on event.
I've tried to insert flags in `pageshow`/`pagehide` (as I found in [another SOW answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21142755/2929433), but these events seems to not being called on background running.

Also, I wasn't able to control that through the Page Visibility API and inserting flags in it's callbacks: even if events gets called when going in background, "overriding" `HTMLMediaElement.play()` does not work and the problem concerns iOS's Control Center.

It is like it does not use `HTMLMediaElement.play()`...

Does anyone have a clue on how to override Control Center's "Play button" behavior from web? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like Youtube fully unloads the content when the browser goes on the background and reloads the content starting at the point the user "interrupted".
I decided to follow the same way.

Moreover, the same iOS behavior seems to happen also on Android notification center (when Chrome shows you a tab is reproducing audio).