# disable audio from keeping playing after lock screen or press home button in safari

Tags: html, ios, web, html5-audio

I'm working on a project and in a case I need to play audio using  tag in web. But I found out that the audio won't stop after lock screen or press home button. It just keeps playing. So is there a way to disable that? BTW I tried simplest way but the audio won't stop. Here's the code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <audio src="./movies/1.mp3" controls="controls">
            Your browser does not support the audio element.
        </audio>
    </body>
</html>
```

Maybe. I can listen to some event like hitting home button or lock screen and pause()? But I don't know if that possible.

Comment: Maybe I can listen to some event like hitting home button or lock screen and pause()? But I don't know if that possible.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of a loop, to check if the user is on the webpage. Store the time.

Here is my code with jQuery:

```
var lastSeen
var loop = function (){
    lastSeen = Date.now()
    setTimeout(loop, 50)
}
loop()
var media = $('audio, video')
media.each(function () {
  this.addEventListener('timeupdate', function () {
    if(Date.now() - lastSeen > 100) {
      this.pause()
    }
  }, false)
})
```

source: [Stop HTML5 audio from looping when iOS Safari is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414654/stop-html5-audio-from-looping-when-ios-safari-is-closed/14438227#14438227)